# How to use Protractor.by.selectedOption

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to check the text of selected option from a drop down. I read somewhere that protractor has selectedOption but I can't seem to get it work. I used

```
ptor = protractor.getInstance();
var elemement = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.selectedOption('data.model'));
expect(elem.getText()).toEqual('some text');
```

Suppose I have for the dropdown

```
<select class="..." ng-model="data.model">
```

but I got error:

```
 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selectedOption'
```

What should I pass as param to selectedOption, and why do I get this 'object has no method' error? Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I used to work with selectedOption and with the latest protractor releases it stopped working.

I now use:

```
element(by.model('data.model')).getAttribute('value').then(function (selectValue) {
        expect(element(by.css('select option[value="' + selectValue + '"]')).getText()).toEqual(expectedText);
    });
```

The selectedOption never worked in phantomjs en this works in all browsers, so for me it's an improvement.

Comment: Thanks Andre for providing the sample code. One question, if I want to pass a variable instead of actual value to by.model, how should I do it? I tried using by.model("' + modelName + '"), it didn't work for by.model, although the same syntax worked for by.css

Comment: I figured I just need to pass modelName in and it works.

Comment: This is great. I created a helper method for this and stored it in params.udf in protractor.conf.js. Works by ID instead of CSS. Here's the function in case anyone is interested:

`getSelectedValueFromModel : function(model,fieldId,callback) {
 var mdl = model,
  fId = fieldId,
  callback = callback;
 mdl.getAttribute('value').then(function(selectValue){
  element(
   by.css('select#'
    + fId 
    + ' option[value="'
    + selectValue + '"]
   )
  )
  .getText()
  .then(function(value) {
   callback(value);
  });
 });
}`

D'oh! No block coding in comments...leaving it just in case...

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in Protractor for Chrome (slightly modified/shortened from Andre's answer):

```
expect(element(by.model('data.model')).getAttribute('value')).toBe(expectedText);
```